# How to Damage Player after each Second if he is on Spikes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got Spikes and the bool `onSpikes`, which tells if the player is onSpikes or not.
Currently the health goes Down constantly, if the player is onSpikes.

```
if(onSpikes)
    {
        health -= 0.01f;            
    }
```

But I think this it isn't a good solution, cause I'm in void Update(), and I anyways wanted the Health to drop in bigger pieces ( like -0.2f each second).

I've already tried building an Method and use Invoke, but like this my player didn't lost health at all.
Code:

```cs
    private void Update(){
        Debug.Log("Player on Spikes: "+SpikeDMG.onSpikes);
        bar.localScale = new Vector3(health,1f);

        if(SpikeDMG.onSpikes)
        {
            Invoke("doDmg",1);
            
        }


        //Wenn leben unter 0 fällt ==> starte szene neu
        if(health <=0){
             int scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(scene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            SpikeDMG.onSpikes = false;
        }
    }
    
    void doDmg(){
        health -= 10/100;
    }
    
}
```

Thanks to everyone who can help!

Comment: Could you provide a bit more code ?

Comment: Can you provide the full example where you tried Invoke? The standard way for something like this would be to use [InvokeRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)(EDIT: the time parameter, when the method should start can't be 0!) and [CancelInvoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke.html)  once the player should not take damage anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is use some kind of time stamp, when your next action should be executed. It is also described [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/651425/using-invokerepeating-in-the-update-method.html) and [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/17131/execute-code-every-x-seconds-with-update.html).

```
private float spikeDamageAt= 0.0f;

void update() {    
    if(onSpikes && Time.time >= spikeDamageAt) {
        health -= 0.01f;
        spikeDamageAt= Time.time + 1.0f; // for 1 seconds
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, but I'd name the variable `spikeDamageAt` instead of a generic `timeStamp` that cat relate to anything.

Comment: @trollingchar right makes more sense, I was just quickly adapting the solutions found to OPs code. Gonna edit it