# How to decrease value of float over time in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a game in Unity in which my character slides when space key is pressed down. He can only slide when running or sprinting. When player starts sliding, player speed should decrease over some time, meaning he can't slide forever or at the same speed all the time.

I've tried doing another float that has constant value, and reduce player speed with that constant over time passed (Time.deltaTime). However, it only reduced the time once by that value, it needs to do it every second.

```
float playerSpeed=5.2f;

Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && (isRunning == true || isSprinting == 1))
    {
        isSliding = true;         
    }      
    else
    {
        isSliding = false;
    }
}
```

I expect player speed to decrease from 5.2 to 0 in 2 seconds.

Comment: can you include the code where you substract the player speed as well?

Comment: Shorter code: `isSliding = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && (isRunning || isSprinting == 1);`

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I noticed that you mention the speed should reduce "every second". I would reduce my speed every cycle instead, spreading out the reduction to 0 over the two second span as a percentage. That would make the slide a whole lot smoother.

Comment: Shouldn't the property/variable named `isSprinting` be a boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After modifying phantasm's answer, I figured it might be better to just write a more complete answer myself even if it does use a concept mentioned in that post.

You should be able to use the following, with some slight modification for your sprite being in a stopped state, etc... This is just the basics of the concept for using [Mathf.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html)

```
private float playerSpeed = 5.2f;
private float slideDuration = 2.0f;
private float remainingSlideTime = 2.0f;

void update() {  
    bool isSliding = (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && (isRunning == true || isSprinting == 1));
    if(isSliding && remainingSlideTime > 0 && playerSpeed > 0) {
        remainingSlideTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        float speedReduction = playerSpeed * (Time.deltaTime/remainingSlideTime);
        playerSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(playerSpeed - speedReduction, 0, remainingSlideTime/slideDuration);
    }
}
```

You, of course, do not need to use `Mathf.Lerp` to accomplish what you are looking to do, and in this case it might be best to do away with it...

```
private float playerSpeed = 5.2f;
private float slideDuration = 2.0f;
private float remainingSlideTime = 2.0f;

void update() {  
    bool isSliding = (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && (isRunning == true || isSprinting == 1));
    if(isSliding && remainingSlideTime > 0 && playerSpeed > 0) {
        remainingSlideTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        float speedReduction = playerSpeed * (Time.deltaTime/remainingSlideTime);
        playerSpeed = ((remainingSlideTime/slideDuration) > 0) ? playerSpeed - speedReduction : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, non Mathf.Lerp solution worked. Problem was on my side. I had 2 more playerspeed floats conflicting in existing else conditions. I removed them to see what is happening and it worked. Thank you everyone for motivation and really good advices!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something every second / minutes / whatever time frame while a condition is true you can have a look at [How to damage a player after each seacond ..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56967952/how-to-damage-player-after-each-second-if-he-is-on-spikes/56969412#56969412)
Here is a quick adaption of my answer in the other question:

```
private float timeToDoStuff = 0.0f;
private float slidingDecrease = 0.0f;
void update() {  
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && (isRunning == true || isSprinting == 1))
    {
        if(!isSliding) slidingDecrease = playerSpeed / 2;
        isSliding = true;         
    }      
    else
    {
        slidingDecrease = 0.0f;
        isSliding = false;
    }
    if(isSliding && Time.time >= timeToDoStuff) {
        playerSpeed -= slidingDecrease; // or whatever
        timeToDoStuff = Time.time + 1.0f; // for 1 seconds
    }
}
```

Now this decreases from x to 0 in 2 seconds when you only apply it every second. So if you want to decrease it ever 0.5 seconds you obviously have to adjust the calculation of slidingDecrease.

Comment: Could be my fault, but nothing happens when I do this code, even when playing with numbers. Could be other variables affecting this.

Comment: @Mactadilis hm, could be that I made a mistake somewhere as well, as I just adapted it really quick. You can try using a fixed value for slideingDecrease first and later add a way to calculate it dynamically

Comment: Now that i found conflicting variables, this is also working method with little modification.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look

```
float playerSpeed = 5.2f;
float slideTime = 2f;

/* ... game loop logic, etc... */

if(isSliding && playerSpeed > 0) {
    playerSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(5.2f, 0f,  slideTime);
}

/* ... more game loop logic ... */
```

Edit:

This function linearly interpolates between **a** and **b** by **t**, where **a** and **b** are numbers, and **t** is a time. Please refer to this documentation : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html

Comment: This may provide a partial solution to the problem, but it would be a lot more helpful if you gave a bit more of an example how this function is used, more exposition on the usage of this function, and finally a link to a reference page as well.

Comment: This just reduces player speed from 5.2 to 0. It doesent slowly decrease. Also, t parametar is clamped between 0 and 1, so time can only be max 1, so i get from documentation.

Comment: @Mactadilis You should probably work with a `timeRemainingInSlide` variable of type `float` that you decrement by `Time.deltaTime` on each iteration, Use that to calculate the percentage of time elapsed in the slide. That can be represented as a value between 0 and 1 rounded to the nearest 10th. Also, the solution that phantasm suggested, I simply modified it to use the basic suggestion they posted. A lot of refinement could be done while still using the `Mathf.Lerp` method that would make for a smoother slide to stop.

Answer (score -1):

I want to provide some explanation on the `Mathf.Lerp` method,
to help anyone who's interested understand the math procedure.

The script below can help you figure it out:

```cs
float start = 5.2f; // Could be any number.
float end = 0;  // Could be any number too.

float totalTime = 2; // The time it takes to transit from start to target.
float t; // The variable holding the current time passed.

void Update() {
    t += Time.deltaTime; 

    float T = t / totalTime; // The percentage of our "progress" towards totalTime.
    float currentFloat = Mathf.Lerp(start, end, T); 
    Debug.Log(currentFloat);
}
```

The function for lerp is: `start + ((end - start) * T)`
with the addition of clamping the T you provide between 0 and 1.
So with the values I provided it's: `5.2 * (1 - T)`

Link to the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html